# Can I read data from a 'hash field' in a legacy Ingres database?

Tags: index

I have been asked to read and present data from the 'hash fields' of an Ingres 2.0 database, which are apparently multiple pieces of data stored together in a single field in various combinations. I know nothing about Ingres 2 and there is no documentation that I've been able to find. Apparently because the tables aren't indexed or some such the only way to get the data I need to present is from these hash fields.

Everyone at the client company appears to be working under the assumption that reading the data out of these fields is possible, but they do not know HOW this is to be done. I've been given information about which field stores which combination of data, but nothing about how it is encoded (for lack of a better word). Its like staring at a black box. My real concern is that the names suggests that the data is hashed, and therefore non-reversible by design.

Does anyone have any insights that could shed some light on this?